# How to create a database with multiple objects and data attached to it

Tags: objective-c, database, cocoa-touch, ios7, nsuserdefaults

I want to create a class that each time I call a method like init I can pass parameters like date and time and timerTime. Then I want to save the object. But I possibly could want to run some code determining the colour property of the object inside the method. I need to be able to create a lot of these without overwriting the old ones then retrieve them.

What I'm currently doing is I have a class called dots. I modified its init method to take some variables and then I use NSKeyedArchiver to archive a array. I also use it to retrieve that array later on by passing a BOOL as No to the init method. the problem here is that I can only create 1 data object but I want a DIFFERENT object to be created each time this is called and not create 1 object and then overwrite it. Here is the code:

```
- (id)initWithTime:(NSDate *)dateTime colour:(UIColor *)color time:(int)time retainerCycled:(BOOL)retainerCycled andShouldArchiveData:(BOOL)shouldArchiveData {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        if (shouldArchiveData == YES) {

            //configure our variables
            // 7200 = 2h || 10800 = 3h
            if (time < 7200) {
                color = [UIColor greenColor];
            } else if (time >= 7200 && time < 10800) {
                color = [UIColor yellowColor];
            }else if (time > 10800) {
                color = [UIColor redColor];
            }

            //save the entrie
            data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dateTime, color, time, retainerCycled, nil]];

        } else {

            //get all our entries back
            NSArray *entries = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:entries forKey:@"dots"];
        }

    }
    return self;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I've been looking around and I saw that possibly for each object I could create a property list with a key for each property that I need and then name each plist created differently and store those names or the amount of plists in a array to retrieve all of them later. Also each object one is created cannot be modified.

**ANSWER:**

What I have done is the following. First I set a integer in NSUserDefaults to 0. I then add the following code to a custom class:

```
- (id)initWithTime:(NSDate *)dateTime colour:(UIColor *)color time:(int)time retainerCycled:(BOOL)retainerCycled {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        //configure our variables
        // 7200 = 2h || 10800 = 3h
        if (time < 7200) {
            color = [UIColor greenColor];
        } else if (time >= 7200 && time < 10800) {
            color = [UIColor yellowColor];
        }else if (time > 10800) {
            color = [UIColor redColor];
        }

        //save the entrie
        //increment the number of saved dots by one
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"dotNumber"] + 1 forKey:@"dotNumber"];
        //save the array with a key which is dotNumber followed by the number of the dot
        NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dot%i", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"dotNumber"]];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dateTime,color,time,retainerCycled, nil]forKey:keyString];


    }
    return self;
}

-(NSArray *)getDotForNumber:(int)dotNumber {
    //create the key string with the number passed to us
    NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dot%i", dotNumber];

    //get array
    NSArray *array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:keyString];

    return array;
}

-(NSMutableArray *)getAllDots {
    NSMutableArray *allDots;

    for (int a = 1; a <= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"dotNumber"]; a++) {
        //create the key string
        NSString *keyString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"dot%i", a];

        //get array back
        NSArray *array = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:keyString];

        //add array to the allDots array
        [allDots addObject:array];
    }

    return allDots;
}
```

The first class I call to create the array, the key is determined by the number of arrays saved before it that's where our saved variable comes in. We increment that by 1 each time we create a new array. This also allows us to identify each 'dot' with a special number. We use that number in the getDotForNumber: method. To get all dots we get the number of arrays already created from the variable saved in NSUserDefaults and run a for loop. We then add each array that we created to an NSMutableArray now all we have to do is extract it later on with objectAtIndex: in another for loop and do all our code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on File > New > Choose Objective C Class

Name your class dots and subclass NSObject

This will create two files dots.h and dots.m

In dots.h

```
@interface dots : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate* dateAndTime;
..... other properties of your object

@end
```

in dots.m

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

       //do here what you need to do on initialisation of object (like setting the color depending on the time of day)
     }
    return self;
   }
```

Comment: How can I retrieve the dots?

Comment: You just create them in the view controller: `#import dots.h` at the top and then `dots *dot = [[dots alloc] init];`

Comment: Ok so that's to create a dot. But I want to store them so I can show them in a collection view later on like the above. How do I do that? Should I use a array?

Comment: Maybe update your answer to reflect that no code necessary just so I can mark it as an answer.

Comment: I did yesterday they edited it out because it's not related to the original question.

Comment: Oh. Can you try again maybe now that I requested it they will let it through. Also please see edited question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46957/discussion-between-ge0rges-and-mikael)